# Javascript not executing with PHP

Tags: php, xss

I am playing with PHP, going through some security tutorials. I tried to demonstrate a very basic XSS attack. If I simply use `echo "Test<script>alert(1);</script>";`, it displays a javascript alert box, but when I try to **POST** the same text using a form and then echoing it back on the browser doesn't give me javascript alert box. Just displays **Test**.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$text = isset($_POST['text'])? $_POST['text']: NULL;
if ($text) {
    echo $text;
}

$test = "Test<script>alert(1);</script>";
echo $test;
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Security</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<label for="text">Put some random text here:</label>
   <input type="text" name="text">

   <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: working for me.what is your browser ?

Comment: Which browser did you try it in which it doesn't work? Try it in a different browser.  If I remember correctly chrome prevents JavaScript from running which appears in the querystring or post.

Comment: @Ultimater I was trying that in Chrome. Works perfectly fine in Firefox. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your source code after submitting the form.....

```
<script>alert(1);</script>Test<script>alert(1);</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Security</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<label for="text">Put some random text here:</label>
   <input type="text" name="text">

   <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```